# content (fusion chart swf) is going out of iframe and overlaps with parent content, when parent page is scrolled down

Tags: html, asp.net, fusioncharts

I am using fusion charts,
I dont have any issues in getting data and appending it.

The problem is that when i have my application inside an iframe, 
the fusion chart part alone goes above the iframe and overlaps with content above it in
the parent page when the parent page is scrolled up.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try setting wMode on FusionCharts using `.setTransparent(false)` on your chart instance before you render.